# flying-saucer-pdf Table 'name' does not exist in exception on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, pdf

I have a simple spring boot web app, where i create downloadable pdf with [flying-saucer-pdf](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) from html that i render with thymeleaf. It's work well and generate the html string correctly. I develop on windows and during develop generating the pdf is also works well, but on ubuntu server don't work.

```
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(fontFile, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

fontFile is exist, on ubuntu too, it's accessibly by the program, and can access it, but when i want render a pdf i got the following exception.
I have no ide what actually it means.

> Caused by: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException: Table 'name' does not exist in
>   /opt/RFIT/TextileApp/conf/font/Rubik-Regular.ttf
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.getBaseFont(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode.(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
>           at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addFont(ITextFontResolver.java:201)
>   ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.6.jar:na]
>           at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addFont(ITextFontResolver.java:193)
>   ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.6.jar:na]
>           at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addFont(ITextFontResolver.java:188)
>   ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.6.jar:na]
>           at hu.rfit.textile.service.impl.PdfPrinterService.printPDF(PdfPrinterService.java:53)
>   ~[TextileApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:4749]

on some forum they said i should add the font to /usr/share/fonts dirt, and re build the font cache. But it's does not work.

Comment: Could you please approve my answer? @Syngularity

Answer (score 16):

I had same problem about adding font with flying-saucher.
Problems main cause is cropped font file. Your operating system or maven filtering may cause this problem. In my example, i used maven and following steps are solved the problem.

If you are using maven, you should add font file to your resource folder.

For example,

> src/main/resources/fonts/samplefont.ttf

After that, you should define resources on pom.xml like following;

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>fonts/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>fonts/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

After that, you can use following definition,

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/fonts/samplefont.ttf",
                                    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
                                    BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: You should make this an answer @Syngularity. At least in my case this was the issue.